# How to stream VLC video to HDMI on TV? (wired, no Wifi)

Tags: video, hdmi, vlc-media-player, tv

I connected my laptop (dell inspiron 3521) to my TV thru HDMI ports, every thing is working well, my desktop screen is displayed on TV, when I open VLC and stream some video I click on full screen button option on VLC to display the video full screen on TV and on laptop. I would like to ask how to set VLC video output to display full screen only on my TV then I could use the laptop for other things and keeping watching VLC video on TV. I have VLC 2.1.6 running in Trusty 14.04. I added a screenshot showing display>video>output options, but I don't know which option of output is for HDMI plugged on TV.[VLC video output settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyI8W.png)

Comment: There are a few options... you could set it as a second monitor and then drag your video to it, you could setup some third party device that supports apple airplay and then stream to that device which plays on your screen (which I do believe VLC support sending to). Just a few ideas but whichever you chose is up to you

Comment: You don't say what operating system you are using. Windows (since at least Windows 7) allows you to "Extend your display" so that the TV's screen is part of the same logical screen as the laptop's (it will be to the left or the right of it). You can drag the VLC window sideways so that it in on the TV screen, and you can then do other things on the laptop's screen.

Comment: Please [edit] you question to add relevant information, do not use comments for that and especially not as an answer. With any xUbuntu it's exactly the same as described above: Simply drag the (not-maximized) VLC windows to the screen where you want it and only then maximize it.

Comment: Since you now stated that you use xunbuntu, here is an answer to your question https://askubuntu.com/questions/62681/how-do-i-setup-dual-monitors-in-xfce

Comment: I will try these suggestions, I'm sorry that